# Cordova installation and NPM path on Windows

Tags: windows, cordova, installation

I have installed cordova with npm install -g cordova and NPM path is C:\Users{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm but I want to install everything (specially cordova) on some other drive rather than 'C'. Not sure how it is possible.

Comment: If your goal is to free up space in an SSD drive, move the Android SDK to another drive, and keep Cordova and NPM where they are.

Comment: Space was not the concern and I already had SDK in another drive.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by installing cordova without '-g' as it does global installation.
To install cordova to desired location just change the directory to that location in command prompt and run below command

npm install cordova

and to check installation

cordova --version.